# Determine Which Hard Drive the Database-Files/Transaction-Files are Stored

Tags: unix, sybase, hard-drive, sun

I have an old Sybase server whose database is acting up.  I have tried rebuilding the file-system and the database file.  But the problem returns.  I want to replace the hard drive that the database-files and transaction-files are stored.  I want to determine exactly which hard drive it is because I am not familiar with Unix.  Moreover, I also want to see if those files are stored in the same hard drive as the operating system or not; if they are, I will need to re-install the operating system as well as restoring the database to the new hard drive.  Obviously this will be better if the database-files and the transaction-files are not in the same hard drive as the operating system.  Please help me to determine these two things.

So far, I have found these:

(1)  I use **sp_helpdb** command and find that the database files and the transaction files are stored in these logical devices:

```
sybdbs
syblogs
master
sybdbs2
```

(2)  I use **sp_helpdevice** command to look into those 4 logical devices shown above, and find that those logical devices are in these physical devices:

```
/dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s1
/dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s4
d_master
/dev/rdsk/sybdbs2
```

(3)  When I use **sp_helpdevice** to show all the physical devices, I see this:

```
device_name        physical_name                               description                                      status cntrltype device_number      low     high
------------------ ------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------ ------ --------- ------------- -------- --------
historydump        /export/home/syb11.dump/history.dump        disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
isproddump         /export/home/syb11.dump/isprod.dump         disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
istestdump         /export/home/syb11.dump/istest.dump         disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
master             d_master                                    special, physical disk, 100.00 MB                   2       0           0              0    51199
masterdump         /export/home/syb11.dump/master.dump         disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
modeldump          /export/home/syb11.dump/model.dump          disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
prodtestdump       /export/home/syb11.dump/prodtest.dump       disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
sybdbs             /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s1                          special, default disk, physical disk, 2000.00 MB    3       0           3       50331648 51355647
sybdbs2            /dev/rdsk/sybdbs2                           special, physical disk, 1.00 MB                     2       0           5       83886080 83886591
syblogs            /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s4                          special, physical disk, 850.00 MB                   2       0           4       67108864 67544063
sybscurty          /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s5                          special, physical disk, 100.00 MB                   2       0           2       33554432 33605631
sybsecuritydump    /export/home/syb11.dump/sybsecurity.dump    disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
sybsystemprocsdump /export/home/syb11.dump/sybsystemprocs.dump disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
sysprocsdev        /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s4                          special, physical disk, 100.00 MB                   2       0           1       16777216 16828415
tapedump1          /dev/rmt4                                   tape,        625 MB, dump device                   16       3           0              0    20000
tapedump2          /dev/rst0                                   disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0    20000
uniface724dump     /export/home/syb11.dump/uniface724.dump     disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
uniface7dump       /export/home/syb11.dump/uniface7.dump       disk, dump device                                  16       2           0              0        0
```

(4)  I want to know more about those physical devices.  I use the **df** command to examine them:

```
df -k /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s1    
df -k /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s4    
df -k d_master    
df -k /dev/rdsk/sybdbs2
```

The df command complains that the first three devices are “not a block device, directory or mounted resource”.

On the other hand, the df command shows the following info for the last device:

```
Filesystem        kbytes   used  avail capacity Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0 576558 371019 147889    71%   /
```

In any case, this doesn’t tell me which drive(s) those devices are on.

(5)  When I use the mount command, I see this:

```
/            on /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0 read/write/setuid on Mon Jul 6 11:10:46 2015
/usr         on /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s6 read/write/setuid on Mon Jul 6 11:10:46 2015
/proc        on /proc             read/write/setuid on Mon Jul 6 11:10:46 2015
/dev/fd      on fd                read/write/setuid on Mon Jul 6 11:10:46 2015
/tmp         on swap              read/write        on Mon Jul 6 11:10:49 2015
/export      on /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s7 setuid/read/write on Mon Jul 6 11:10:49 2015
/freespace   on /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s5 setuid/read/write on Mon Jul 6 11:10:49 2015
/sybase      on /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 setuid/read/write on Mon Jul 6 11:10:49 2015
/usr/openwin on /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s3 setuid/read/write on Mon Jul 6 11:10:49 2015
```

I cannot figure out the connection between the mounted devices above to the physical devices for the database-files and the transaction-files.  I also cannot link the mounted devices above to the hard drives shown in the next section.

(6)  When I use the **cat /etc/vfstab** command, I see these:

```
#device              device              mount         FS     fsck  mount    mount
#to mount            to fsck             point         type   pass  at boot  options
#
#/dev/dsk/c1d0s2     /dev/rdsk/c1d0s2    /usr          ufs    1     yes      -
/proc                -                   /proc         proc   -     no       -
fd                   -                   /dev/fd       fd     -     no       -
swap                 -                   /tmp          tmpfs  -     yes      -
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0    /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s0  /             ufs    1     no       -
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s6    /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s6  /usr          ufs    1     no       -
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s7    /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s7  /export       ufs    2     yes      -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s5    /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s5  /freespace    ufs    2     yes      -
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0    /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s0  /sybase       ufs    2     yes      -
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s3    /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s3  /usr/openwin  ufs    2     yes      -
/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s1    -                   -             swap   -     no       -

# The following lines have been commented-out to allow Sybase to access these
# partitions and Raw Partitions.  Nov-24-1999
# /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3  /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s3  /master       ufs    2     yes      -
# /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1  /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s1  /sybdbs       ufs    2     yes      -
# /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s4  /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s4  /syblogs      ufs    2     yes      -
# /dev/dsk/c0t3d0s5  /dev/rdsk/c0t3d0s5  /sybscurty    ufs    2     yes      -
# /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s4  /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s4  /sybtemproc   ufs    2     yes      -
```

(7)  When I use the **format** command, I see these two hard drives:

```
AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
 0. c0t0d0 <IBM-DNES-309170-SA30 cyl 11195 alt 2 hd 5 sec 320>
    /iommu@f,e0000000/sbus@f,e0001000/espdma@f,400000/esp@f,800000/sd@0,0
 1. c0t3d0 <SEAGATE-ST34520N-1206 cyl 9004 alt 2 hd 4 sec 246>
    /iommu@f,e0000000/sbus@f,e0001000/espdma@f,400000/esp@f,800000/sd@3,0
```

(8)  I don’t see any external device attached to the Sybase server.  Having said this, there is a backup Sybase server, and the backup Sybase server has an external device attached to it (through a SCSI cable).  At this point, I assume the database-files and transaction-files are all stored inside the Sybase server.

By the way, the Sybase server uses this Unix operating system:

```
SunOS <my-server-name> 5.4 Generic_101945-62 sun4m sparc
```

And the Sybase version is:

```
SQL Server/11.0.3.2/P/Sun_svr4/OS 5.4/SWR 7578 Rollup/OPT/Mon Nov  3 22:19:21 PST 1997
```

By the way, what I have tried so far to repair the database are:

•   Tried **dbcc checkalloc(, fix)**.  Unfortunately, this command could not fix and could not complete.

•   Tried **drop-db/add-new-db/restore-db-from-backup**.  Unfortunately the restore failed to complete.

•   Tried **fsck-to-fix-the-devices**.  It could not complete and complained about “MAGIC NUMBER WRONG”.

•   Tried **Analyze-option-in-format-command-to-repair-Disk-0, and then add-new-db and restore-db-from-backup**.  This method seemed to work.  But after one week or so, I found a table has I/O error.  Honestly, I don’t even know if the databases are really in Disk-0 or not.

Please help me to determine which hard drive those database-files and transaction-files are stored, and whether they are in the same hard drive as the Unix operating system.

Thanks in advance.

Jay Chan

Comment: How about checking the mount table via `mount` ?

Comment: Can you tell us the actual Sybase version (select @@version), as well as give us the actual output of sp_helpdevice, and sp_helpdevice [devicename] .  The devices you have listed are actually logical device names, not physical device names (even though they look like physical names).  sp_helpdevice [devicename] should give you both the logical, and physical device name.

Comment: I have added the info from mount and sp_helpdevice to my post above.  Hope this will be useful.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added the info from the file vfstab that shows the list of file systems that the operating system is expected to mount during startup.  It shows some devices related to /dev/rdsk that may be closed to the file-systems where the database-files and transaction-files are stored.  Unfortunately being close is not good enough because none of them match.  I still don't know where those files are stored.

Comment: [Disclamer: I don't know Sybase] Could it be that Sybase is using raw partitions, circomventing the filesystem layer?

Comment: Sybase IS using raw partitions in this case, as noted by the /dev/rdsk -

Comment: Based on the comments in /etc/vfstab, sybase may be using raw partitions.  OK, I will ask this question in a Sybase related forum.

Comment: @JayChan That version of Sybase is more than 15 years old.  I'm not sure what commands would be available for moving or mirroring devices since my experience only goes back to 11.9.2.  You may have to find the documentation to see if disk mirroring is available, and if not, then you may have to `dd` the disk at the OS level to get it off the faulty drive.